# Managing onChange event for multiple rows

Tags: reactjs

When editing a column for multiple rows the onChange behaviour does not work as expected. When I update the column for row 1 it updates the value for that column for all rows. How do I manage the onChange event so it changes the value for the row.

[image]

Code for table:

```
    <table className="table_display_data">            
          {this.state.array.map(item => (
            <tr key={item.itemId} className="table_tr_data">
              <td>{item.sku}</td>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td><TextField id="quantity" label="Quantity" style={{width:'25%'}, {paddingBottom: '12px'}} value={item.values} onChange={this.handleChange(item.itemId)} /></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          </table>
```

Code for handleChange:

```
handleChange= text=> (event) => {
      this.setState({ values: event.target.value })    
    };
```

My array has the following properties:

```
public int itemId { get; set; }
public string sku { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public int values { get; set; }
```

Comment: `this.setState({ values: event.target.value })` this updates the value in the state. You have to filter out the particular row here.

Comment: Please post your state here.

Comment: Actually you try that if quality of item1 is changed, update array state in states. Because you render to state "array" in table. Am i understand currently?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField id="quantity" 
    name={item.sku} 
    label="Quantity" 
    style={{width:'25%'}, {paddingBottom: '12px'}} 
    value={item.values} 
    onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)} />
```

in this TextField add a **name props** and **pass event  to handleChange function**

```
handleChange= text=> (event) => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })    
    };
```

and copy this function code